# Get pandas items at selected intervals

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am trying to find a faster way of selecting dates at varying intervals. Currently, I am looping through the data frame and then finding the required interval spans using `iloc`. The performance is causing a bottleneck though. The files are huge and there many of them, so any help welcome.

```
#example
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='01/01/1980', end='01/01/2020'), columns=['DT'])

n = 5
spans = []
max_len = len(df) - n
for k in df.index:
    if k < max_len:
        spans.append([df.iloc[k].DT, df.iloc[k + n].DT])
```

Is there a "better" way of doing this, i.e. faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can shift `DT` column by required amount:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='01/01/2018', end='01/01/2020'), columns=['DT'])

df['DT2'] = df['DT'].shift(-5)
print(df[df['DT2'].notna()])
```

Prints:

```
            DT        DT2
0   2018-01-01 2018-01-06
1   2018-01-02 2018-01-07
2   2018-01-03 2018-01-08
3   2018-01-04 2018-01-09
4   2018-01-05 2018-01-10
..         ...        ...
721 2019-12-23 2019-12-28
722 2019-12-24 2019-12-29
723 2019-12-25 2019-12-30
724 2019-12-26 2019-12-31
725 2019-12-27 2020-01-01

[726 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#example
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='01/01/1980', end='01/01/2020'), columns=['DT'])

n = 5
spans = []
max_len = len(df) - n
for k in df.head(max_len).index:
    spans.append([df.iloc[k].DT, df.iloc[k + n].DT])
```

Comment: That's no faster than the original, but a novel method for dealing with a loop, will use it in future.